# String' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible' in Xcode 7 Beta 5

Tags: xcode, string, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to initialize a dictionary constant with

```
["updateType" : "moveRow", "data" : rows].
```

rows is an array.  I have is as:

```
let update = ["updateType" : "moveRow", "data" : rows]
```

I have also tried:

```
let update: Dictionary< String, AnyObject> = ["updateType" : MoveRow", "data" : rows]
```

and

```
let update: [String : AnyObject] = ["updateType" : "moveRow", "data" : rows]
```

in each case, I get and error on the key `"data"` that says:

> String' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'.

Can anybody explain what's going on?

Comment: How exactly is the `rows` defined?

Comment: `var rows: Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>?` I have added data to it by using .append(["item1": anInt, "item2": aFloat])

Comment: When only adding 1 item to the initialization, it works.  for example `let update: Dictionary< String, AnyObject> = ["data", rows]`  or ` let update: Dictionary< String, AnyObject> = ["updateType" : MoveRow"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your creation of `rows` as optional:

```
var rows: Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>?
```

If you can get rid of the optional, it should start working. E.g.

```
let d = ["updateType" : "moveRow", "data" : rows!]
```

...or by creating the rows like this:

```
var rows = Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>>()
```